# Цикличная анимация css БЕЗ animation

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css, php

Как сделать цикличную анимацию при помощи css без свойства animation.
К примеру, делаю hover по элементу, и его фон становится красным (при помощи transition это все делаю плавным), а потом возвращается прежний фон (допустим желтый). И так циклично. Красный-желтый-красный-желтый. Без использования animation. То бишь только transition. Возможно ли каким-нибудь изощренным способом это реализовать только на css? Или нужно что-то еще? Если JS - то расскажите, пожалуйста, подробно - как. Я в нем не силен. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp - есть свойство infinity

Comment: **БЕЗ animation**

Comment: мне кажется только js, если без animation, при наведении начинаем переключать через setTimeout класс элемента, (jquery toggleClass например), при выходе из элемента, перестаем переключать, выставляем в default.

Comment: Эм.. Не то же...

Comment: А чем animation не угодил?

Answer (score 1):

Можно через `jQuery  mouseenter/mouseleave` отлавливать и включать таймер анимации, но дабы не перегружать процессор без дела я бы при наведении мыши менял бы фон на анимированную картинку, а при покидании объекта - возвращал бы назад `background:transparent;`